# Install exe file silently using CMD and PowerShell

Tags: docker, powershell, cmd, inno-setup

I am trying to install an exe created using Inno Setup.
When I try to install it using PowerShell with

```
Start-Process -wait C:\updatefile.exe /VERYSILENT
```

all folders are created at proper places, registry values are created, but console hangs and does not return unless <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is pressed.

But if I install exe using command prompt with

```
start /wait C:\updatefile.exe /VERYSILENT
```

everything goes properly and command prompt returns.

What could be cause of this anomaly?

I need this exe to install through Dockerfile, but as PowerShell install is hanging, container does not install exe. Even with `cmd` version in Dockerfile, container does not create install folders.

---

After checking logs I found that exe service is being started by installer in end. If that is reason for hanging, is there some argument I can use to exit PowerShell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-Wait` switch of PowerShell's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet also waits for *child* processes of the launched process to exit<sup>[1]</sup>, whereas `cmd.exe`'s internal [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command does not.

- As you note in a later comment, a *service* executable is launched by your installer at the end; given that services run indefinitely, `Start-Process` also waiting for *that* (child) process to terminate indeed explains the hang.

Here is a simple *workaround*:

```
cmd /c C:\updatefile.exe /VERYSILENT
```

When an executable is called via `cmd /c`, `cmd.exe` implicitly waits until the executable's process - and only it - terminates, even if it is a GUI application, just like `start /wait` would.

---

Given the behavior described in footnote [1], another workaround is to use the `-PassThru` switch with `Start-Process` (instead of `-Wait`) and pipe the result to [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process):

```
Start-Process -PassThru C:\updatefile.exe /VERYSILENT | Wait-Process
```

---

<sup>[1] See [GitHub issue #15555](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15555), which also discusses that [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) acts differently in that only waits for the process *itself* to terminate.

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, the behavior of `Start-Process -Wait` is now at least *briefly* mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process#-wait) as well (emphasis added): "waits for the specified process *and its descendants*".</sup>

Answer (score -2):

try

$arguments = "/Verysilent"
Start-Process -wait C:\updatefile.exe -ArgumentList $arguments

Comment: That is effectively the same as `Start-Process -wait C:\updatefile.exe /VERYSILENT`, and therefore cannot be expected to make a difference.

Comment: Aside from that, allow me to suggest [formatting your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).